# I need such output but not getting my query result

Tags: mysql, sql

There is two Table and i want output as show below :-

**COUNT is what ,In second table you can see 65 have two record so count = 2
same as 66 have one record so count = 1**

[image]

i had try :

```
SELECT *
FROM prayerrequest
LEFT JOIN encouragements ON prayerrequest.userid = encouragements.userId
WHERE encouragements.userid =27
```

Comment: what would You like to have in 'count' column as result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple sample that you can modify anytime:

```
SELECT prayerrequest.*, encouragements.encid FROM prayerrequest
INNER JOIN encouragements ON prayerrequest.userid = encouragements.userId
WHERE encouragements.prtid = 65;
```

I assumed that "count" is a column under Table2.

---

[Edited]

Sorry to misinterpret your problem. I think you should know more about [MySQL Functions and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/functions.html) in order to create queries easily. Anyway, here's what I conclude:

```
SELECT prayerrequest.*, COUNT(encouragements.prtid) as count FROM prayerrequest
INNER JOIN encouragements ON prayerrequest.prayerId = encouragements.prtid
GROUP BY encouragements.prtid;
```

Comment: Can you please try the edited code above? I think there's a trouble in calling the column names.

Comment: Hey, can you try again the latest code I made above? Under the edited part. I just thought you need a simple assistance. I guess you need further studies in MySQL.

Comment: somewhat true but still getting wrong output. i'm getting prayerId 20. why ?

Answer (score 1):

please use inner join and select specific fields from both table not `*`